# SQL Server Compact 3.5: Process/import CSV data

Tags: csv, sql-server-ce

I have a CSV file which I wish to manipulate using SQL Server **Compact** (CE) 3.5

How can I bulk insert the data into a temporary table?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the csv data into a DataTable and the load it using http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com - you could use http://www.csvreader.com/ and avoid loading into a DataTable.